# serializing a tree map after every one minute using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, time, treemap

I am attempting to store all the object of the class Message obtained in one minute into a tree map against its precise time as key.After the completion of one minute, I am trying to interrupt the thread and serialize the map as `ObjectOutputStream` to byte[] which I want to return to the calling class.

```
    public class StoreMessage {
        private static long start_nanotime=System.nanoTime();
        private static Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
        private static int timeToRun = 60000; // 1 minute
        private static byte[] b=null;
        public static Map <Long,Message> map1=new TreeMap<Long,Message>();

        public static byte[] store(Message message){
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                sleep(timeToRun);
                thisThread.interrupt();
                b=serializer.serialize(map1);
                            } 

                catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
               }
            }).start();

    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            long precise_time=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(System.currentTimeMillis())+(System.nanoTime()-start_nanotime);
        map1.put(precise_time, message);

        }
    return b;
  }
}
```

Why is this code not working?
It is giving me `Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Answer (score 1):

This code makes very very little sense:

1. Why are you extending `Thread` and implementing `Serializable` in the enclosing class for no apparent reason?
2. Why does your thread interrupt the parent after finishing to sleep? It seems to me like you are doing a very complicated control flow manipulation.

I suggest a much more simple approach, using a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to run the serialization task every minute, while the main thread keeps updating the map with new messages.

After a bit of studying I understand how your program works, but it's very hard to read how the control flows.

Comment: Could you please help...I am stuck real bad